# How to simulate a login to Amazon in MCU?

Tags: browser, login-with-amazon

I would like to login to Amazon without browser so that I can get the "code" returned by Amazon which process is running on a MCU. Since MCU cannot run a browser so I cannot use a browser or headless browser to simulate the login process.

Do anyone have any idea to do this ?

Also, since I found that the page "index.html" which hold the "Login with Amazon" button and has Amazon login SDK "https://api-cdn.amazon.com/sdk/login1.js" would redirect to "https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?..." with different parameter values after clicking the "Login with Amazon" button, can I skip the page "index.html" and go to the Amazon login page directly ?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

You can manually compose the login page URL that the JavaScript SDK composes, but depending on the type of grant, you'll need an https page as your origin or an https page to return to.